# Installing Fedora Core 12 on a VPS

Tags: linux, vps

I'm working on a Linux VPS that is running FC6, and I want to reinstall with the latest version FC12. The VPS is running on the Virtuozzo platform. I am also running Plesk on the VPS. This is all managed hosting through Network Solutions, so I don't have access to the actual box.

My question is, how does one reinstall a different OS through Virtuozzo? I see "reinstall VPS" in virtuozzo, but this just burns a fresh copy of FC6?

Is this a host-by-host thing, or are there best practices for accomplishing this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is Guest OS are you using if you running any Linux then you install http://www.mondorescue.org/ take image of your live os it will be around 4 GB plus, or if you are using any microsoft os then you use any of the symantec back /ghost software take image then reinstall fc12 and virtuozzo

Answer (score 0):

If the reinstall VPS thing only offers you the option to reinstall FC6, then you need to get in touch with your host, otherwise it will likely offer a list of options, and it will also delete the contents of your VPS, so be careful.

Comment: Do you mean that my host should offer a list of OS options when I reinstall VPS? Meaning Virtuozzo should be equipped to setup one of many distributions?